# Attribute not changing in frontend

Tags: magento, attributes, frontend

I created an attribute and include it in my attribute set. The attribute is Multiselect with 6 different values. Now when i import my csv with the value for the sku everything looks fine on the backend, the product shows the attribute with the value assigned from the csv file but does not show anything on frontend, not even after reindexing and cleaning cache.

It will only show if i open the product and save it. Not changing anything other than what the csv file already changed. Then it will show on frontend.

Now... in my csv file i'm only have sku, attribute_set and Type which is the attribute i need to change.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Are there translations present for your attribute? It might be that the data is just not updated for the storeview you are looking at.

Comment: No translations.... What i find really weird is that when you access the product from the backend the attribute is there... with the value assign by the csv file... but this doesn't reflect on the frontend.

Comment: And the attribute options itself? (manage attributes => Check if it is displayed)

Comment: yes they are displaying... let's say i upload the csv, i go to the backend and  the attribute is there with the value, but this doesn't display on frontend... but, if i save the product i already opened with the value from the csv, THEN it will show on frontend.

At the beginning i though it was a lag problem with my server but then i tried locally and i get the same results... 

i'll keep looking and if i found the answer i'll share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following after a new import of products.

Check your csv file and confirm that you're importing product options in Magento format:

Open the attribute:

> admin/catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id

and ensure its visible on the frontend and set to global.

Ensure that the reindexing for product attributes is ready/done:

> /admin/process/list/

Flush cache

> /admin/cache/index/

Delete cache folders in

> root/var

If that fails to work, do what I did. Export a current product that has the attributes you wish. Change the attributes/sku and reimport the same file back in.

I tested the following file for color: Green and it updated instantly:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,color,cost,country_of_manufacture,created_at,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,description,gallery,gift_message_available,has_options,image,image_label,manufacturer,media_gallery,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,minimal_price,msrp,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,name,news_from_date,news_to_date,options_container,page_layout,price,required_options,short_description,small_image,small_image_label,special_from_date,special_price,special_to_date,status,tax_class_id,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,updated_at,url_key,url_path,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled
3,,Default,simple,,,base,Green,,,"2015-03-12 00:00:23",,,,,1,,,0,no_selection,,,,,,,,,"Use config","Use config",1,,,"Product Info Column",,9.9900,0,1,no_selection,,,,,1,2,no_selection,,"2015-03-15 17:44:00",1,1.html,4,1.0000,555555.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,,Default,simple,,,base,Green,,,"2015-03-12 00:02:16",,,,,2,,,0,no_selection,,,,,,,,,"Use config","Use config",2,,,"Product Info Column",,14.9900,0,2,no_selection,,,,,1,0,no_selection,,"2015-03-12 00:02:16",2,2.html,4,2.0000,423555.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Explore if another extension is interfering with your import. If you can, try to test on a vanilla installation.

If attributes are still stale after doing so I strongly recommend you explore Magmi product import to avoid such squirrel-ly vanilla magento import behaviour:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/